# Custom field bug in Wordpress 3.2

Tags: custom-field, customization, ajax

I have a question.
I just installed Wordpress 3.2. And ever since then, when I want to add a custom field, precisely when I clicked on "Add custom field", my page is refreshed. And no custom field is added.

What is it ? Ajax bug ? Wordpress 3.2 ?

Can you help me please ?

Comment: You've already reinstalled WP and deactivated all plugins.  My next recommendation would be to switch to the default theme (some themes try to act like plugins).  Also, what browser are you using?  Do other AJAX functions work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to re-install your wordpress, it might help you,
and also try using different browser, to check the cache problem

Comment: Yep, it's done. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @Steffi did you reinstalled the wordpress?

Comment: Yes, I did... =/

Comment: Well, the last thing you can try is disable all plugins and switch to the default theme (twentyeleven).

Comment: Yes, I did it too...